# How can i avoid subscription for the same planid for the same buyer?

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox, paypal-subscriptions

I'm trying to implement PayPal Subscription button using https://www.sandbox.paypal.com/billing/plans.
Everything works using the API but the problem is that I want to avoid multiple subscriptions for the same buyer and the same plan_id.

Is there an option to configure that on PayPal or i have to do it manually? is the last option, what is the best way to do it?

Answer (score 0):

You have to do it manually. With a smart JS button, I think you'd have to cancel/deactivate any duplicate subscriptions after the onApprove function (since at that point it's been created).  With a redirect integration, you should be able to do validation *before* creating/activating the subscription with the final API call.